# Use layouts with meteor-router

Tags: layout, meteor

From this discussion here,

[Allow a passed in variable to {{renderPages}} helper](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router/commit/f83b808f4a6f7c683a551345962cfa448125b7c4#commitcomment-2820919)

I am trying to display a template within an existing {{renderPage}};

My Use case: I have a very simple high level body template

```
<template name="body">
    {{> header}}
    {{> notifications}}

    <div class="content" id="content">
        <div id="main-content">

            {{{renderPage}}}

        </div>
    </div>
    {{> footer}}

</template>
```

And as you can see, my main-content has the `{{renderPage}}`. This works great, when i set up a route:

```
 '/home': 'home'
```

The route finds the template 'home' and replaces renderPage with that template. I want to expand that now and see if route templates can be placed within specific divs.

For example, in my home.html template:

```
<template name="home">
        {{#if isAdmin}}
                <h1>student</h1>
        {{/if}}
        <div id="inner_home">
                  {{renderPage innerHome}}
         </div>
</template>
```

Is it possible to have a different route `/home/tools : 'home_tools` render it's template not in the highest main content div but within my child div `inner_home`?

EDIT:

I am evaluating an approach that just uses JQuery and the callback function of the meteor-router method to grab the template i am looking for and add it directly to the concerning div tag.

Something like:

```
 var foundTemplate = _.template($('#item-template').html())
  $('#div_example').html(foundTemplate); //
```

If anyone has a better approach, please let me know.

Comment: Is anyone using sessions to just update part of the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

### client.js

```
Meteor.Router.add({
  '/home/tools': function() {
    Session.set("homeTemplate", "tools");
    return 'home';
  },
  '/home/admin': function() {
    Session.set("homeTemplate", "admin");
    return 'home';
  }
});
```

### home.js

```
Template.home.homeTemplateTools = function() {
    return Session.equal("homeTemplate", "tools");
};

Template.home.homeTemplateAdmin = function() {
    return Session.equal("homeTemplate", "admin");
};
```

### home.html

```
<template name="home">
    {{#if isAdmin}}
            <h1>student</h1>
    {{/if}}
    <div id="inner_home">
    {{#if homeTemplateTools}}
      {{> homeTools}}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if homeTemplateAdmin}}
      {{> homeAdmin}}
    {{/if}}
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Sir thank you for the detailed explanation. This works great. My only concern is that this becomes very unstructured as the level of inner templates within my home.html grow. If for example, i have an inner_home2 where i must constantly set and check sessions just to display templates. I guess this will work for now